# How to enforce date formats in Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect UML Stereotypes' Defined Tag Types?

Tags: date-format, enterprise-architect

If I have a Defined Tag Type, called "published date" for a Stereotype called "wiki article" with:

Type=DateTime;
BaseStereotype=wikiarticle;

Then Sparx pulls the date format from the User Desktop preferences of the Individual user and then stores a string in the t_objectproperties table. The result is a mix of different date types like:

1/9/2017
02/02/2018
2018-02-21
Where only the last one (ISO 8601 is unambiguous).

Is there way I can enforce these data formats the in Sparx?

Comment: No. I remember this has been discussed on their forum. EA is messy on quite a number of places. i18n is one of them Report a bug, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: I think the only workaround is to use an add-in using **Type=AddinBroadcast;**

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible within Enterprise Architect.
But for one othe the customer we did it through an addin.

All you need to do is define a tagged value with **[Type=AddinBroadcast](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/modeling_tools/predefinedtaggedvaluetypes.html)**

and in your addin add the broad cast event **[EA_OnElementTagEdit](https://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_onelementtagedit.html)**

```
public void EA_OnElementTagEdit(EA.Repository Repository, int ObjectID, String TagName, String TagValue, String TagNotes)
{
    DatetimePickerForm form = new DatetimePickerForm(); //Form designed for time picker
    form.ShowDialog();

    // Assign values for TagName,TagValue and TagNotes
}
```

And if you clicked that tagged value a datetime picker similar to EA will be displayed.

[image]

Format of the datetime picker can be customized.Please refer here for [full list of formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)